UBUNTU 24.04.1 Desktop crashed unexpectedly
The OS on one of my PCs was Ubuntu 24.04.1. Yesterday there was some problem in Livepatch. To set the matter right I followed the guidelines so given in  https://github.com/snap-stanford/snap/issues/240 and then sudo pro enable livepatch.
During the period I received 2/3 messages saying “Sorry Ubuntu 24.04.1 had experienced an internal error” and I opted to send the error report to Ubuntu.
I turned off the computer after the update was finished.
But today when I turned on the computer, after booting, a message came on screen that “Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can’t recover. Please contact a system administrator.”
What to do now? Whether I  have to install the OS afresh? Or is there any other alternative? How do I recover my documents etc.? I do not have any backup in any external device. Kindly guide.

You can run a live system from an installation media and instead of installing Linux, mount your harddisk and copy your data.

@Bodo - Thanks for you cooperation. As I'm not so expert like you and others, I need certain clarifications. I'm having bootable USB Media which was created from an ISO image of UBUNTU 22.04. Whether this will serve the purpose? And if so, please advice as to how I would use it in the PC for recovery of old records from the hard disk.

@ Bodo - Thanks, I did.
